# create 10000 files with size 4k by using bash?

Tags: bash

I want to do this.
Create 10000 files, (filename can be just combination of time and random number).
File size should be 4k.
And I want to time this. say how many seconds it will take.

How can I do this on bash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time for x in {1..10000}; do
  dd if=/dev/zero ibs=4k count=1 of=$x.txt 2>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: *sigh* let's hope he can create the filenames...

Comment: curious, can you read from /dev/null? Or is that why you use /dev/zero?

Comment: @Hawken: /dev/null is, as the name says, empty (it has zero length)

Comment: Could read `/dev/urandom` too. I wonder what the time difference would be.

Comment: thank you Karoly. What does "if=/dev/zero" do here? Thanks again

Comment: @andersLind /dev/zero is the Input File for `dd` hence `if=`; /dev/zero is a device file that when read from (I assume) emits the value `zero`. I don't know if that means zero as in `0x00` or `0x31`.

Comment: @kevin Reading from /dev/urandom would take longer, especially if you read enough that the entropy pool is depleted. Reading from /dev/zero is easier in terms of cpu cycles, as you're guaranteed to never fall back on generating pseudo-random numbers. Quick test confirms; that script with /dev/zero takes ~12 seconds compared to ~15 from /dev/urandom. (But I'm watching movies and other stuff while playing, so take with a fairly large pinch of salt).